# How to warn user if he/she accidentally close/leave session at website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, session

We develop accounting system on a web with ASP.NET MVC and encountered this problem - if user is in the middle of the work and somehow manages to close browser all work is gone (and users are not geeks at all it did happen and will happen). Especially problematic at Chrome in Windows after they removed warning of closing tabs from philosophical reasons so now it will just shut down. We would like to be able to somehow catch this behavior. Also even when Firefox for example has warning that user is going to shut down his tabs - simple clicking the checkbox will remove it all again. So is it possible to keep track of this action to prevent user accidentally closing browser and lost all the work? Or is it even possible to do for example in Chrome? The solution would be simple warning window but it needs to show basically everytime if closing while our web application is alive. We don't want to keep session alive after closing browser for obvious security reasons. Also - it should work at Chrome, IE and Firefox. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Basically you want user not to close the tab without saving current work?

Comment: Yes basically that. So if he would accidentally click on X button to close browser/tab (we are switching to web app from standalone client so users are use to do that there) he would get the warning he is not logged off (or he is in the middle of work)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
   return "Are you sure you want to exit";
}
```

Comment: Kindly let me know if you don't find the answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

If your front end is using MVVM such as AngularJS or Knockout, or any of the other popular binding libraries, consider a different approach to preventing the user from quitting the page.

In a client-side interval, serialize your view model and store it in local storage. 
When the save/exit condition for the current page is met, clear the local storage.

If the page is loaded again, and there is something in local storage, this means that on the previous session, the browser was closed before saving - so deserialize the local storage object back into the viewmodel (use a unique key per page) - you can combine this with some UI that tells the user that their previous state has been restored, click ok to continue or start over to start again (which would reset the viewmodel)

I should add that you'll have to watch out for multiple simultaneous tabs, so you may want to work around this by making the key unique somehow, e.g. creating two invoices simultaneously.

This essentially provides an auto-save but client-side only.

You can combine this technique with using window.onBeforeUnload as per Tejinder's answer, but as you cannot style the "unload confirmation" prompt, providing an auto-resume is a much better experience.